# auditing who has access to my page

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to write an external application to retrieve access rights data for a particular page. I want to find out who currently has administration rights to my application. Is this possible? I couldn't retrieve this data with fql or graph...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with FQL:

```
SELECT uid FROM page_admin WHERE page_id = YOUR_PAGE_ID
```

You can also get this via the Graph API. To do it in the [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

- In the below `PAGE_USERNAME_OR_ID` is a valid username or ID of a page you manage.
- Query `/PAGE_USERNAME_OR_ID?fields=access_token` with the `manage_pages` permission and copy the `access_token` for the page in question.
- Paste this access token into the "Access Token" dialog.
- Query `/PAGE_USERNAME_OR_ID/admins`

Comment: Are you using the page access token on the call to `/PAGE/admins`? If not, that's working as intended i think - 'subject' refers to whoever's access token you're using